# Visual Studio for Mac 2022 - missing 'Web and Console'

Tags: console-application, visual-studio-mac, visual-studio-mac-2022

after updating Visual Studio 2019 To 2022, I can't create a console app anymore.
[image]

I expected to have something like this:
[image]

I tried to reinstall VS few times and tick all items below but still not work:
[image]

Comment: For the Web and Console section to be displayed you should only need to install the .NET  SDK, which from the installer screenshot, that seems to be the case. I would check Visual Studio for Mac's Preferences - Projects - SDKs and Locations - .NET Core and see if the path registered there is /usr/local/share/dotnet and if the .NET SDK is being found. My only guess is that dotnet is being found on the PATH at some non-default location, and there are no .NET SDKs available there.

Comment: thanks!  I can do it now (the path I used: Visual Studio>preference>build and debug>Sdk Locations>.Net Core)

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I tried this fix but the SDK was already found by VS. I did the full uninstall of .NET and then reinstalled it using Visual Studio Installer for Mac but I'm still missing the Web and Console section :(